# Как добавить объект в map?

Tags: c++, map

Правильно ли я добавляю пару значений в map?

```
cout << "Size: " << ((map <BYTE,ifunct*>)FuncBytes[sign]).size() << endl;
((map <BYTE,ifunct*>)FuncBytes[sign]).insert(pair<byte,ifunct*>(n,changMethod));
cout << "Size: " << ((map <BYTE,ifunct*>)FuncBytes[sign]).size() << endl;
```

Что до, что после insert-а size() возвращает нуль. То есть значения не добавились?

Comment: когда перестанете чудить, тогда все получится. А пока вы каждый раз конвертируете FuncBytes[sign] в какой то новый обьект  map <BYTE,ifunct*>.

Comment: Что такое `FuncBytes[sign]`? Почему эта информация отсутствует в вопросе? И зачем вы постоянно делаете это приведение типа `(map <BYTE,ifunct*>)`?

Comment: @AnT, отсутстыует, потому что он  с этии кодом уже третий день задает вопросы

Comment: @AnT, FuncBytes[sign] и есть map<byte,ifunc*>. Сам FuncBytes - это вектор. Кастую, тк тогда в иде автокомплит кода показывает методы map. Так удобно

Comment: Захламлять код такой ужасной вещью, как каст, только ради автокомплита - идея более чем странная. Но если бы вы делали каст к типу `(map <BYTE,ifunct*> &)`, то временные объекты бы не создавались и все бы работало как ожидалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше явное приведение типа `(map <BYTE,ifunct*>)` создает временный объект типа `map <BYTE,ifunct*>`. Каждое такое приведение типа создает индивидуальный временный объект, который автоматически уничтожается в конце выражения. Все действия, которые вы делаете, вы делаете именно с такими временными объектами. Добавление элемента тоже делается в один из этих временных объектов и, разумеется, исчезает без следа вместе с ним.

Объект `FuncBytes[sign]` вашими действиями никак не затрагивается.

Comment: стреляем в воздух, при охоте на зайцев

Comment: Чудеса. Ни за что б не подумал!) Где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: Про C++? В любой книжке про C++, ещё можно кликнуть по метке C++, там есть ссылка на список литературы.А ещё на [гитхабе free-programming-books](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books).

Comment: @Александр  вообще основной прикол в том что олератор [] вектора отдаёт вам ссылку на объект (const или не const), а приводите вы не к ссылочному типу. А ещё можно написать для класса оператор приведения типа свой собственный. Ну это я к тому `что` почитать.

Comment: @vegorov, вопрос был конкретно про создание временного объекта при кастовании. Чтобы на него ответить, мне нужно пересчитать все темы раздела с пометкой с++ или список литературы от корки до корки?

Comment: @Александр На вскидку не нашёл. Просто запомните что когда вы кастуете к типу (не к ссылке и не к указателю), а к просто типу, то получаете временный объект. А QtCreator свежий кстати умеет autocomplit, который вам был нужен. Проблема исходная в этом была, насколько я понял.

Comment: @vegorov, ага, без него как-то неуютно

Comment: @Александр добавил пример.

Answer (score 1):

Пример для более полного понимания что происходит при явном приведении типов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Bar;
class Foo{
public:
    Foo():
        m_id{makeId()},
        m_data{}
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::Foo() self id: " << m_id << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(int data):
        m_id{makeId()},
        m_data{data}
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::Foo(int) self id:" << m_id << std::endl;
    }
    int getData() const{
        return m_data;
    }
    void setData(int data){
        m_data = data;
    }
    Foo(const Foo& other):
    m_id{makeId()},
    m_data{other.m_data}{
        std::cout << "Foo::Foo(const Foo& other) self id: " << m_id << "  other id: " << other.m_id << std::endl;
    }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other){
        std::cout << "Foo::operator=(const Foo& other) self id: " << m_id << "  other id: " << other.m_id << std::endl;
        if (this != &other){
            m_data = other.m_data;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    virtual ~Foo(){
        std::cout << "Foo::~Foo() self id: " << m_id << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static int makeId(){
        return m_idCounter++;
    }
    int m_id;
    static int m_idCounter;
    int m_data;
};


int Foo::m_idCounter = 0;

class Bar{
public:
    Bar():
        m_id{makeId()},
        m_data{}
    {
        std::cout << "Bar::Bar() self id:" << m_id << std::endl;
    }
    Bar(int data):
        m_id{makeId()},
        m_data{data}
    {
        std::cout << "Bar::Bar(int) self id:" << m_id << std::endl;
    }
    Bar(const Bar& other):
        m_id{makeId()},
        m_data{other.m_data}
    {
        std::cout << "Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:" << m_id << " other id:" << other.m_id << std::endl;
    }
    Bar& operator=(const Bar& other){
        if (this != &other){
            m_data = other.m_data;
         }
        std::cout << "Bar::oeprator=(const Bar& other) self id:" << m_id << " other id:" << other.m_id << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    int getData() const{
        return m_data;
    }
    void setData(int data){
        m_data = data;
    }
    operator Foo() const{
        return Foo(m_data);
    }
    virtual ~Bar(){
        std::cout << "Bar::~Bar() self id:" << m_id << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static int makeId(){
        return m_idCounter++;
    }
    int m_id;
    static int m_idCounter;
    int m_data;
};

int Bar::m_idCounter = 0;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Foo f = 1;
    Bar b = 2;
    f = (Foo)b;
    std::cout << "before create vector" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
    bars.reserve(5);
    std::cout << "before emplace back" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        bars.emplace_back((i+1)*10);
    }
    std::cout << "after emplace back" << std::endl;
    for (auto& item: bars){
        ((Bar)item).setData(100);
        std::cout << ((Bar)item).getData() << std::endl;
    }
    for (const auto& item: bars){
        ((Foo)item).setData(100);
        std::cout << ((Foo)item).getData() << std::endl;
    }
    for (auto& item: bars){
        ((Bar&)item).setData(100);
        std::cout << ((Bar&)item).getData() << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Foo::Foo(int) self id:0
Bar::Bar(int) self id:0
Foo::Foo(int) self id:1
Foo::operator=(const Foo& other) self id: 0  other id: 1
Foo::~Foo() self id: 1
before create vector
before emplace back
Bar::Bar(int) self id:1
Bar::Bar(int) self id:2
Bar::Bar(int) self id:3
Bar::Bar(int) self id:4
Bar::Bar(int) self id:5
after emplace back
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:6 other id:1
Bar::~Bar() self id:6
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:7 other id:1
10
Bar::~Bar() self id:7
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:8 other id:2
Bar::~Bar() self id:8
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:9 other id:2
20
Bar::~Bar() self id:9
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:10 other id:3
Bar::~Bar() self id:10
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:11 other id:3
30
Bar::~Bar() self id:11
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:12 other id:4
Bar::~Bar() self id:12
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:13 other id:4
40
Bar::~Bar() self id:13
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:14 other id:5
Bar::~Bar() self id:14
Bar::Bar(const Bar& other) self id:15 other id:5
50
Bar::~Bar() self id:15
Foo::Foo(int) self id:2
Foo::~Foo() self id: 2
Foo::Foo(int) self id:3
10
Foo::~Foo() self id: 3
Foo::Foo(int) self id:4
Foo::~Foo() self id: 4
Foo::Foo(int) self id:5
20
Foo::~Foo() self id: 5
Foo::Foo(int) self id:6
Foo::~Foo() self id: 6
Foo::Foo(int) self id:7
30
Foo::~Foo() self id: 7
Foo::Foo(int) self id:8
Foo::~Foo() self id: 8
Foo::Foo(int) self id:9
40
Foo::~Foo() self id: 9
Foo::Foo(int) self id:10
Foo::~Foo() self id: 10
Foo::Foo(int) self id:11
50
Foo::~Foo() self id: 11
100
100
100
100
100
Bar::~Bar() self id:1
Bar::~Bar() self id:2
Bar::~Bar() self id:3
Bar::~Bar() self id:4
Bar::~Bar() self id:5
Bar::~Bar() self id:0
Foo::~Foo() self id: 0
```

Comment: Спасибо, чуть позже испробую